# Using GetModuleFileNameExW in VB.Net

Tags: c++, vb.net, winapi

I've got the following code in C++:

```
    DWORD _intLen;
    LPWSTR lpFilename = new wchar_t[200];
    DWORD nSize = 200;
    //get process file path
    _intLen = GetModuleFileNameEx(1000, NULL, lpFilename, nSize);
```

Now I' trying to use this in VB.Net:

```
  Public Declare Function GetModuleFileNameExW Lib "PSAPI.DLL" (ByVal hProcess As Integer, ByVal hModule As Integer, ByRef lpFilename As String, ByVal nSize As Integer) As Integer


    Dim _intLen As Integer
    Dim lpFilename As String
    Dim nSize As Integer
    nSize = 200
    lpFilename = Space(400)

    'get process file path
    _intLen = GetModuleFileNameExW(1000, nothing, lpFilename, nSize)
```

which results in the following error:

[image]

Any Ideas?

Addition Notes: I've tested the code with the string builder:

```
Public Declare Function GetModuleFileNameExW Lib "PSAPI.DLL" (ByVal hProcess As Integer, ByVal hModule As Integer, ByRef lpFilename As StringBuilder, ByVal nSize As Integer) As Integer

        Dim _intLen As Integer
        Dim lpFilename As StringBuilder
        Dim nSize As Integer
        nSize = 200

        lpFilename = New StringBuilder()
        'also tried this
        'lpFilename.append(space(nSize))
        'and this
        'lpFilename = New StringBuilder(nSize)

        _intLen = GetModuleFileNameExW(1000, 0, lpFilename, nSize)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your p/invoke declaration (which we cannot see) is wrong. You need to declare the filename to be a `StringBuilder`. That's because the data flows from the callee to the caller. It is an out parameter.

The p/invoke declaration from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/psapi.getmodulefilenameex) is accurate and can be used:

```
<DllImport("psapi.dll")> _
Public Shared Function GetModuleFileNameEx(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal hModule As IntPtr, <Out()> ByVal lpBaseName As StringBuilder, <[In]()> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal nSize As Integer) As UInteger
End Function
```

This is a rather pointless exercise though. The managed `Process` class already does what you need. Get a `Process` object representing the external process. Get the main module of the process with the `MainModule` property. Then obtain the file name with the `FileName` property.

Comment: I've added the declaration statement I'm using in the question. Also I've tested the code with the stringbuilder and I"m still getting the same error. I've added the stringbuilder code to the question

Comment: Don't use Declare. That's for compat with VB6. Use p/invoke. But here use process.MainModule.FileName.

Comment: Could you please explain how? Where do I use this process.MainModule.FileName

Comment: How are you identifying the process? Normally you start with a process id

Comment: I get the process ID from "EnumProcesses" then I pass that to "OpenProcess" to get the handle and thats what I'm passing to this function. I've cut all the extra code out. The first parameter (1000) basically comes from an array that comes from some other function.

Comment: Process.GetProcessById(id).MainModule.FileName